# Handling recurrence relations

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, recursion, visualization, difference-equations

Are there special features in Mathematica for probing a recurrence relation? (dummy example: $f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^N f(x-i)$)

Such as, potential simplification, finding base cases, or a visualisation of its iterations.

*As an amateur user, any hints would be highly useful.*

Comment: Maybe this helps: `Table[RSolve[f[x] == Product[f[x - i], {i, 1, n}], f[x], x], {n, 0, 
   5}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk ah this is neat. If there are conditions for side-cases, e.g. if `x<0, f(x)=0`, how do I include them in the RSolve as written by you?

Comment: You mean Include a boundary condition?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk yes it can also be seen as some form of boundary condition. The reason I ask, it is because in the documentation of mathematica we have only examples of the kind `RSolve[a[i + 1, j + 1] == i j a[i, j], a[i, j], {i, j}]` but what if we wanted to add a condition of the kind `a[i,j]=0 if i=j`, in the RSolve, an immediate attempt like this `RSolve[{a[i + 1, j + 1] == i j a[i, j], a[i,j]=0 if i==j}, a[i, j], {i, j}]` doesn't seem to work.